# MobileFirst 6.3 Network Debug Issue

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MobileFirst 6.3 for an application, when building an Android version and trying to monitor XHR Query on Chrome Dev Tool network, queries are not showing,

I used to see them with previous worklight versions.

I saw that there is a new plugin WLNativeXHRPlugin in 6.3 + versions, is it related to my issue?

Any Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XHR requests have been moved from the JavaScript layer to the native layer, and this is why you do not see them in the Network tab in the Chrome dev tools.

You can bring them back, but you must then not forget to remove this code from the app when you go to production. It is also **not supported** and can break/stop working at any moment, any effect that may happen to your app will not be supported.

Add the following to the bottom in common\js\initOptions.js:

```
WL.androidProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
WL.iphoneProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
WL.ipadProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
WL.windowsphone8ProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
```

Should then work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

Well, this brought QUERY back to monitor but i have an issue :

queries are not passing to server and they start all with file://...android/query...

Comment: @Idan , is there anyway to log/monitor native xhrs ?

Comment: You should still be able to see full network traffic using tools such as WireShark and alike. If your traffic is encrypted (SSL) it will be more involved to get it to monitor that traffic, but doable.

Comment: Thanks Idan but one last question. Why it has been changed ? Is it for security reasons ?

Comment: By doing this processing in the native layer this allows seamless session sharing in an application with both native and web views.

Comment: I use Wireshark to debug whenever possible but when I'm using https and want to use this feature I have this : POST file:///apps/services/api/iDubai/android/init net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND