# How to trace MobileFirst 7.1 server queries under Network tab while debugging Android devices with Chrome?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Since MobileFirst 6.3, I couldn't find the network queries to the server when debugging MobileFirst app on Android with Chrome for desktop.
How can I enable them ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See here: [MobileFirst 6.3 Network Debug Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966974/mobilefirst-6-3-network-debug-issue)

The XHR requests have been moved from the JavaScript layer to the native layer, and this is why you do not see them in the Network tab in the Chrome dev tools.

You can bring them back, but you must then not forget to remove this code from the app when you go to production. It is also **not supported** and can break/stop working at any moment, any effect that may happen to your app will not be supported.

Add the following to the bottom in common\js\initOptions.js:

```
WL.androidProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
WL.iphoneProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
WL.ipadProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
WL.windowsphone8ProfileData[WL.EPField.SUPPORT_WL_NATIVE_XHR] = false;
```

Should then work.